# d3 stock value line graph: can't draw the line

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a line graph with d3 that will represent the value of the Yahoo stock action.

I put my code in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prmne/) and my data in a `var data` at the end.

I'd guess the problem arrives at line 9, with `var line`, probably badly written. 
Lines 26, 27, 28 `console.log` fine.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I'd think that you wanted to pass the date and close to the line generator rather than the extents

Comment: @user1614080 tried both solutions without any result, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/prmne/1/

There were a few things wrong:

- the definition of `line` should be inside the `draw` to reference `x_scale` and `y_scale`
- the calls in `line` should be to `x_scale` and `y_scale`, not `x` and `y`
- the parameters should be the values you want to plot i.e. `d.date` and `d.Close`
- the definition of `y_scale` should use `y_extent` instead of `[y_extent]`
- the data passed to `datum` should be `data.query.results.quote`